# Problem with parameter families or groups

Tags: javascript, swagger

I have to call this data that comes from Signaturit. The problem is that they are grouped in a kind of family or groups. I'm using Swagger to build the API.

[Name of the parameteres I have to work with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJ4ll.png)

And I can't call those parameters because JS tells me "ReferenceError: created_at is not defined". That error is normal because I'm trying to give it a property that doesn't exist.

But I need to call those parameters and I can't change the way the platform sends me the data.

Code:

```
params: {
        'document[created_at]': req.swagger.params.document[created_at].value,
         created_at: req.swagger.params.created_at.value,
         type: req.swagger.params.type.value,
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

```
'document[created_at]': req.swagger.params["document[created_at]"].value,
```

Like that you can call the parameter.